# How to get Location as Tokens?

Tags: 7, tokens, location

I would like to use a node location values (for example location:country-name) as tokens.
Is it possible to use something like [node:location:country-name] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a solution for this is a patch to the Location module [here](http://drupal.org/node/1056154).